# How to speed up a data loading into InnoDB (LOAD DATA INFILE)?

Tags: mysql, import, innodb, load-data-infile

I want to speed up a data loading.

I use MySQL 5.5, InnoDB and have 1M rows of data (65Mb file). It takes 5 minutes.

What mysql settings and commands affect the speed of LOAD DATA INFILE for InnoDB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can recommend these settings to improve load time:

- innodb_doublewrite = 0
- innodb_support_xa = 0
- innodb_buffer_pool_size = (50-80% of system memory)
- innodb_log_file_size = (a large number - 256M etc)
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

Other than settings, there are some things you can do yourself:

- Create indexes after loading (this is a new optimization with 5.5 / InnoDB plugin).
- Sort the data file before loading.
- Split the data file, and load in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing indexes and triggers. You can re-create them after the load. Also look into using some of the high-load settings in my-huge.cnf instead of the defaults.

Some more innodb performance settings:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but is a trick I've used in the past

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DISABLE KEYS;
LOAD DATA INFILE ... ;
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ENABLE KEYS;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This strategy works for MyISAM, not InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that binary logging disabled if possible.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in a hurry because you are replacing the contents of a live table, then do it this way instead:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE live;
LOAD DATA ... INTO new;
RENAME TABLE live TO old, new TO live;
DROP TABLE old;
```

The `RENAME` is 'instantaneous' and atomic, so you are 'never' down, regardless of table size.

(Hence you don't need to worry so much about speeding up the `LOAD`.)