# How can I improve LOAD DATA performance on large InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, load-data-infile

I have this table with more than 7 million rows and I am `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`'ing more data in the order of 0.5 million rows at a time into it. The first few times were fast, but this addition is taking increasingly long, probably due to indexing overhead:

```
CREATE TABLE `orthograph_ests` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `digest` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `taxid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `header` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sequence` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `digest` (`digest`),
  KEY `taxid` (`taxid`),
  KEY `header` (`header`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12134266 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am developing an application that will run on pre-existing databases. I most likely have no control over server variables unless I make changes to them mandatory (which I would prefer not to), so I'm afraid suggestions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020998/how-to-speed-up-a-data-loading-into-innodb-load-data-infile) are of limited use.

I have read that minimizing keys on this table will help. However, I need those keys for later queries. I'm guessing that if I drop and re-create them would take very long as well, but I have not tested this. I have also read that especially the `UNIQUE` constraint makes the insertion slow. The `digest` column will take SHA256 digests that *must* be unique, and I can't make sure there is no collision (very unlikely, I know, but possible).

Would partitioning help, as suggested [here](http://derwiki.tumblr.com/post/24490758395/loading-half-a-billion-rows-into-mysql)? Could I improve the indexing, e.g., by limiting the key length on the `digest` column? Should I change to MyISAM, which supports `DISABLE KEYS` during transcactions? What else could I do to improve `LOAD DATA` performance?

**Edit:**

After the large insertion, this table is used for `SELECT`s only, no more writes. This large loading is mostly a once-and-done operation, however about 1,000 datasets (of each 0.5M rows) need to be uploaded before this is finished.

I will be using the digest to look up rows, which is why I indexed that column. If there should be a collision, that individual row should not be uploaded.

Putting the `sequence` blob in an external file system is probably not a viable option since I cannot easily impose file system changes on the users.

Comment: "very unlikely, I know, but possible" It is more likely that your server has random memory bit flips. You don't need to plan for SHA-256 collisions.

Comment: Please clarify some things:  Is this table to be used as a reference table, or will you be doing production transactions that change it?  Will you regularly load a half a megarow of new data into it, or is this loading a once-and-done operation?  What is the purpose of your digest column -- will you be using the digest to look up rows in production? If your digest does experience a hash collision, what is your recovery plan?   Have you considered putting your sequence column (your blob) in an external file system?

Comment: Whatever microoptimization you do, unless you can access server configuration or replace mechanical HDD subsystem with faster one - nothing will help. People usually forget that computers aren't magical unicorns, and apps using relational databases are usually slow because IOPS floor of the data persistence device is being hit instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a large amount of data you are loading, and you should expect it to take many dozens of hours, especially on general purpose shared server hardware. There's very little magic (unless you work at Google or something) that will make this job anything but a big pain in the neck. So have courage.

It's a reference table. That means you should immediately switch to MyISAM and stay there for this table.  You don't need InnoDB's transactional integrity features, but you do need MyISAM to disable indexing during loading and re-enable it afterward.  Re-enabling indexing will take a long time, so be prepared for that.

You should consider using a shorter hash than SHA-256.  SHA-1 (160 bits) is good.  Believe it or not, MD-5 (128 bits) may also serve.  MD-5 has been cracked so it's not suitable for secure content authentication.  But it's still a useful hash. A shorter hash is a better hash from your perspective.

If you can disable indexing MyISAM style, it probably doesn't matter much whether your digest key is unique. But you might consider allowing it to be non-unique to save time.

It's hard to make a suggestion about partitioning without knowing more about your data and your server hardware.  But considering this is a reference database, it seems like it might be wise just to bite the bullet for a couple of weeks and get it loaded.

If you have plenty of server disk space, you might consider loading each half-megarow chunk into its own table, then inserting it into the big table.  That might prove to be a good way to deal with the possibility that you might have to reload the whole thing some day.

On shared server hardware, it might make sense to use smaller chunks than half a megarow.

You might consider making a separate id / digest table.  Then you could load your data without the digests and get it done quickly.  Then you could write yourself a stored procedure or client that would create the digests in batches of a few thousand rows each until they were done.  This only works if the stuff being digested is in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input and valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two reasons for data loading to be slow:

1. Write performance in inserting the data itself.
2. Read performance reading existing data in order to load existing data in order to modify existing pages while adding new data.

The write performance issues can be addressed by primarily reducing durability and reducing logging. That's what many of the suggestions you'll find, such as the following settings: `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0`, `innodb_doublewrite=0`, `innodb_support_xa=0`. Reducing the *amount* of data written can be helpful as well, such as by setting `log-bin=0`. It also is not really acceptable to expect your customers to change these durability related settings in existing production systems, though. Changing them is more suited to one-shot bulk loading on dedicated systems than periodically adding data to existing systems.

Bulk-loading `INSERT` (with many rows) or `LOAD DATA INFILE` seek to reduce write *throughput* requirements by writing more data in a single transaction, thus reducing the number of syncs to the transaction logs. Reducing write throughput or increasing write performance can only help to an extent though.

It can also generally be helpful to sort the data by `PRIMARY KEY` before loading, in order to reduce the amount of unnecessary page splits when inserting data into the index structures. However that is of limited use when there are multiple secondary keys, since sorting by `PRIMARY KEY` will necessarily mean that the data is not sorted by at least one secondary key.

The read performance issues are perhaps more interesting, and are frequently the actual performance problem with loading new data into existing tables, especially where secondary keys are present. The best possible thing would be that all of your existing data fits into memory (`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is large enough) such that paging data in and out of the cache is not necessary during loading. Given you're talking about only a few million rows, this may be feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't understand your point about the read performance issues: Do you mean actual I/O read performance? Because I think that my performance problems are related to indexing overhead. About buffering: that might indeed help, but I am using `LOAD DATA`, which, as far as I know, makes no use of buffer pools.

Comment: In InnoDB, the buffer pool is always used. It is the primary mechanism by which data is cached (as pages, not rows). Basically, if the buffer pool is not large enough to hold all of the existing data, when a write needs to modify data that would be on the same page (the key values are near each other) that page must first be loaded into the buffer pool.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, since I have no access to server variables, I'm afraid your suggestions are of limited use in this situation.