# mysql: unknown variable in `my.cnf`

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

I follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020998/how-to-speed-up-a-data-loading-into-innodb-load-data-infile) to speed up loading a big local file (`500+M`, `10+M` rows) into MySQL, adding configurations to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
local-infile=1

# add following code
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
```

but encounter following issues:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_doublewrite=0'
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_support_xa=0'
```

PS: MySQL version

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put them under `[mysqld]`, not `[mysql]`.

Also, make sure that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is about 70% of available RAM.

Even then, you may hit some timeout.

Or you may need to chunk the file up.  (10K rows per chunk might be reasonable.)

Comment: In other words, the CLI doesn't need an innodb buffer? So you need to specify which variables are for the daemon.

Comment: Most things in my.cnf are tunables for the _server_.  That includes any innodb settings.  The clients (`[mysql]` and/or `[client]`) need very little.